# Python __init__() takes 1 positional argument but 3 were given

Tags: python, oop

[image]

[image]

I wrote a matrix class for my assignment.

```
class Matrix():
'''A class to represent a mathematical matrix'''

    def __init__(self, m, n, default=0):
        '''(Matrix, int, int, float) -> NoneType
        Create a new m x n matrix with all values set to default
        '''
        self._head = MatrixNode(None)
        self._m = m
        self._n = n
        self._default = default
```

However, there was an error raised during testing.

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    m1 = Matrix(3,3)
    print(m1.get_val(0, 0))
    m1.set_val(0,0, 3)
    m1.set_val(2, 2, 5)
```

Here is the error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "/Users/Xueli/Desktop/a1.py", line 336, in <module>
   m1 = Matrix(3,3)
builtins.TypeError: __init__() takes 1 positional argument but 3 were given
```

I really dont get this error report.

Comment: Copying your code, fixing the indentation...code runs.

Comment: Is that the actual indentation you have in your code?

Comment: Indentation is significant in python. Your Matrix class has no __init__ method, instead you have a top-level function called __init__

Answer (score 0):

```
class Matrix():
    '''A class to represent a mathematical matrix'''

    def __init__(self, m, n, default=0):
        '''(Matrix, int, int, float) -> NoneType
        Create a new m x n matrix with all values set to default
        '''
        self._head = MatrixNode(None)
        self._m = m
        self._n = n
        self._default = default
```

Without proper indent `def __init__()` is not recognized as `class Matrix()` constructor. See the above modified code.